# Is a continuous map between smoothable manifolds of the same dimension always smoothable?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, continuity, smooth-structures

(My question is inspired by [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/412791/57159), whose

negative answer I showed by a dimension-increasing map.)

Is it the case that for all smoothable manifolds $M_0$ and $M_1$ with the same dimension,

for all continuous maps $\: \hspace{.04 in}f : M_0 \to M_1 \:$, $\:$ there exists a smooth

structure  on $M_0$ and a smooth structure on $M_1$ that make $\hspace{.04 in}f$ smooth?

If no, what if "smoothable" and "smooth" are replaced with "differentiable" and "differential" respectively?

If yes, what if $\: \operatorname{dim}(M_1) < \operatorname{dim}(M_0) \;$?

Comment: I haven't thought this through carefully and I might be missing something, but what if you take a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that isn't locally monotone anywhere (say the Weierstrass function). That can't happen for a differentiable function, and your coordinate maps have to be monotone.

Comment: [That](http://mathoverflow.net/a/77200/5810) would probably do it. $\;$

Comment: In fact, coordinate maps in one dimension are monotone, so differentiable a.e., and it's enough to start out with any function that's not differentiable on a positive measure set.